# Why doesn't readyState == 0 work

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

So my problem is that when I'm using `if(this.readyState == 0)`
It doesn't do its job. I hava e script that loads form with ajax and I have the option to close the form, but then i realised that if i want to open that form again without making new ajax request i would need somekind of variable for it. I have variable called "isOpen" and when xhr readyState is 0 i want it to check if isOpen is true and in case if its true it aborts xhr and shows the form data. Right now it doesn't seem to work as i expected it to.

Here is my whole function for handling this AJAX request.

```
function postPlacesForm() {
var yhteys = new XMLHttpRequest();
yhteys.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var isOpen = false;
    if(this.readyState === 0) {
        if(isOpen === false) {

        }
        else if(isOpen === true) {
            document.getElementById("places").style.display = "block";
            yhteys.abort();
        }
    }
    if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById("places").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        document.getElementById("places").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("ajax_close").style.display = "block";
        isOpen = true;
    }

};
yhteys.open("POST", "/js/ajax_inc/forms/postplaces.php", true);
yhteys.send();
```

}

Comment: not certain, but my guess is that the readyState value starts at `0` and that the `readystatechange` event happens after the `readyState` value has changed to a non-zero value.

Comment: One thing you might do is drop `console.log(this.readyState)` right at the top of the handler function so that you know what it actually is.

Comment: `if(isOpen === false) {` will always be true. ***always.*** so it doesn't matter if readystate is 0 because you won't do anything when that happens anyway.

Comment: What did basic debugging show you when using `console.log(this.readyState)` or `debugger;` using the browser console?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) for `readyState`? What type of debugging have you done?

Comment: `var foo = new XMLHttpRequest
console.log(foo.readyState)`

Comment: I have done console debugging. I just realized that everytime i run my script it sets isOpen to false. It doesn't save the variable, it overrides it because var isOpen = false; declares it every time to false and that's why it doesn't work. I'm trying to look for another solution, maybe if i store it to global variable it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey i got it working somehow with readyState 2. Thank you all and i'm sorry for wasting your time.

Solution code down below

```
var postPlaceFormIsOpen = 0;
function postPlacesForm() {
    var yhteys = new XMLHttpRequest();
    yhteys.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState === 2) {
            if(postPlaceFormIsOpen === 0) {

            }
         else {
            yhteys.abort();
            console.log("test");
            document.getElementById("places").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("ajax_close").style.dispaly = "block";
        }
    }
    if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById("places").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        document.getElementById("places").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("ajax_close").style.display = "block";
        postPlaceFormIsOpen++;
        console.log(postPlaceFormIsOpen);
    }

};
yhteys.open("POST", "/js/ajax_inc/forms/postplaces.php", true);
yhteys.send();

}
```

Answer (score -2):

It looks that you don't understand the `readyState` property yet.

- 0    UNSENT  Client has been created. open() not called yet.
- 1    OPENED  open() has been called.
- 2    HEADERS_RECEIVED    send() has been called, and headers and status are available.
- 3    LOADING Downloading; responseText holds partial data.
- 4    DONE    The operation is complete.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState